# pecl extension not appearing in phpinfo()

Tags: pecl, geoip, php

I have a problem installing php extension. I have read and tried several articles but none of them solves the issue for me.

So I'm installing **geoip** php extension like so

```
yum install GeoIP-devel
yum install php-pear
yum install php-pecl-geoip
```

The installation is successful. Then I have checked phpinfo() to see which php.ini I need to use to include and included extension=geoip.so

Then I have restarted apache like so

```
server httpd restart
```

Now if I check using command line if geoip module appears in a list like so

```
php -m
```

It shows that it is in the list but if I check phpinfo() it is not in there.
and none of the functions work that should be a part of GeoIP extension.

Our server is using centos and I have several php versions installed on it for other reasons the php version I'm using for this project is 5.5.1.8

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?
How do I check if geoip is installed for a correct version of php?

Comment: Do you have the same php on your CLI as running on your apache? Are there additional ini-files parsed for either? What system are you on?

Comment: I have capitalised many Is and Sentence starters.  Also I have marked your commands.  This is done by prefixing them by 4 spaces.  I bolded geoip, this is done by enclosing the word within 2 asterisks.